# Jekyll: Markup Appearing in <p> Tag

Tags: html, jekyll

I've got an issue where my some of my markup from a file in my `_/includes` folder, is being printed to my page inside `<p>` tags.

Here's what's inside my `_includes/gallery.html` file:

```
{% assign rows = page.gallery[include.gallery] %}

    </section> <!-- close this -->
  </div> <!-- and this -->
</div> <!-- this too -->

<section class="image-gallery">
  ...
</section>

<div class="container"> <!-- open this -->
  <div> <!-- and this -->
    <section> <!-- this too -->
```

I'm trying to close out some elements, and re-open them after my `.image-gallery`. But for some reason, my closing and opening tags are being printed inside `<p>` tags

Like this:

```
<pre><code>&lt;/section&gt;
  </code></pre>
    <p>&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;</p>

    <section class="image-gallery">
        ...
```

Is there any way to stop this from happening? It seems to only affect non-closed tags, like the ones in my example. Everything inside `.image-gallery` displays correctly.

Anyone know why this is happening? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I get it.

You including `_includes/gallery.html` from a `.md` file, so markdown first includes, then try to parse the code.

As you code has unopened tags at the beginning (`</section></div></div>`) they are treated as markdown, not html.

Edit:

The solution is to surround your code with :

```
{::nomarkdown}
your code here
{:/nomarkdown}
```

This avoid your html to be parsed by kramdown.

Comment: Man, those two solutions are huge drawbacks. Writing posts in `.md` was a huge reason why I decided to build this site using Jekyll. Refactoring the markup would take a lot of time, and probably a hack of sorts. So weird that content within a `.html` file can't be treated like html.

Comment: You're a lifesaver dude! Was dreading re-thinking all that markup. Thanks a lot, man! Great advert for Stack Overflow.